# Internet Explorer canvas renders different CJK generic fonts

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

In IE11 and even Edge, if you render `fillText` with a generic `.font` like `16px serif`, the result is not always the same as rendering a DOM element with the exact same styles applied. It appears that the canvas element does not respect the `lang` attribute as DOM elements do, and this affects the final rendered font. Standards browsers seem to have no problem with this.

CJK scripts will demonstrate the issue... you can test this with `今日は` ... note that the rendered font still differs even if the `lang` attribute is correctly set to `ja`.

The use case here is to render generic fonts in canvas to match against known fonts to programmatically find which generics are used for a given browser/os/language combination, so it's required that canvas can somehow be forced to behave the same as rendered text in the DOM, or at least somehow detected that it will differ.

Comment: Ps: since there is no way to be sure what's the font used, (nor even if there is only one being used in the same *word*) the first step is to set your canvas `font` to what the element you are checking has. Then, you could compare the DOM size got through [Range.getBoundingClientRect().width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) and ctx.measureText().width in order to remove the fonts that are obviously not the same (>=0.1px difference would do in FF, not sure for IE). But then if mutilple fonts still match, you'd have no way.

Comment: And once again, since you can't even be sure that a single font is being used, even in a single word, you'd have to do it character by character. And I won't talk about [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)

Comment: What I tried to convey through this link is that even for a known set of characters multiple different fonts can be used. And that you won't be able to find which they are.

Comment: "even for a known set of characters multiple different fonts can be used"  When the lang attribute is respected and the characters are limited to a given script, the rendered font will be identical, so this just isn't true. The problem is how to get the lang attribute to be respected. This *is* the use case. I've updated the ticket to provide extra context discussed in the comment but it's basically irrelevant. This method works fine in standards browsers so this entire thread about generics is meaningless to the issue. The problem is the lang attribute.

Comment: Actually even when the lang attribute *isn't* respected, if the characters are all in the same script they will use the same font. The problem is that it doesn't match the DOM rendering, which is where the lang attribute comes into play.

Comment: So here is something for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ygcg2cww/ it only detects if lang on canvas will have an incidence on the font used, but note that for it to have an incidence at least on FF, the canvas element must be appended in the DOM...

Comment: I suppose that might be a start. Unfortunately it isn't *necessarily* true that the lang would have an effect. If kanji fall back to Chinese faces when the lang is unknown then it means that lang=zh would return a false positive even in standards browsers. This also doesn't tell me what the rendered font would be with lang applied in the DOM, which is more or less what I need. I may have to end up hard-coding these values for IE.